# python - Mentions parse regex

Tags: python, regex

I need a help with figuring out, how correctly implement regular expression.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\[(^[a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9][^]]*)]')
```

The main point is to parse statements like 'Text [123|Foo bar] text'.
Human-readable regex is - [0-9|any symbols].

UPD:
expected results:

```
>>> input = 'text [1|Foo bar] text [222|Text] abc'
>>> pattern.findall(input)
[('1', 'Foo bar'), ('222', 'Text')]
```

Comment: Please clarify from what text what you want to extract- explicitly. I failed to understand

Comment: Please provide an example input string, and an expected output.

Comment: At the very least `|` needs to be escaped as `\|`. Unescaped it's the alternate pattern operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\[(\d+)\|([^][]*)]
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY5nW9/1)

Regex:

- `\[` - opening square bracket
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 matching one or more digits
- `\|` - literal `|`
- `([^][]*) - Group 1 matching zero or more characters other than`[`and`]`.
- `]` - closing `]`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/B44wYw):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\|([^][]*)]')
test_str = "Text [123|Foo bar] text"
print (p.findall(test_str))
```